# pause loadInBackgroud() method

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, handler

I use *AsyncTaskLoader*. In the *loadInBackgroud()* method, I use some method from native library (let's call it **any_method()**) that returns boolean value.
I suppose any_method() uses its own thread, so it can return a significant value after a while (first time method return false, and after a while it will be true).
I want to pause loadInBackground thread while any_method() doesn't return true.

Now I do this:

```
public Uri loadInBackground() {
        ...
        final LNI noiseInfo = mEngine.any_method(); // native method
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (noiseInfo == null) {
                    handler.post(this);
                }
            }
        };
        runnable.run();
        ...
        return value;
}
```

and receive this error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: some relevant part of the code is missing

Comment: That must be an interesting library; I can't imagine anything in the 21st century which forces you to implement busy waiting. Are you sure there's no other way via a callback? -- But if you need to implement busy waiting, you need to `Thread.sleep()` in a loop. As long as you're aware what you're doing.

Comment: Thread.sleep() needs milliseconds parameter, not a condition =(

Comment: @ADK Was that a serious comment?

Comment: I use Handler on the same thread as AsyncTask thread, am i right? Why i have got this error?

Comment: My friend, you're getting this error because AsyncTask threads aren't prepared to deal with Handlers. But that's irrelevant because your approach doesn't make the slightest sense. The way you do it, you need to place the code on the main/UI thread. But you should probably do your busy waiting in AsyncTask using a conditional loop and `Thread.sleep`.

Comment: something like this:
while (noiseInfo == null) {
  Thread.sleep(1);
}

Comment: @ADK Something like that. Although I wouldn't want to have this in _my_ code. Also, you should be aware that you may be blocking other AsyncTasks from executing. Is there really no callback mechanism?